# Creating non-math mode substitutes for \overset and \underset not dependent on the amsmath package

Tags: amsmath, stacking-symbols

I have been using `\overset` and `\underset` to stack text, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $\overset{\text{a}}{\text{b}}$ \\
$\underset{\text{c}}{\text{d}}$
\end{document}
```

The results seems better proportioned font size, line spacing, and baseline positioning than other solutions I have found for stacked text, however, recently, I found some incompatibilities between another package and `amsmath`.

- How can I create an alternative to these commands which does not use math mode, but otherwise has identical font sizes and proportions (so that the output is visually the same)?

I found the source code for `\overset` and `\underset` in [amsmath.dtx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.dtx):

```
\newcommand{\overset}[2]{\binrel@{#2}%
    \binrel@@{\mathop{\kern\z@#2}\limits^{#1}}}

\newcommand{\underset}[2]{\binrel@{#2}%
    \binrel@@{\mathop{\kern\z@#2}\limits_{#1}}}
```

It seems to be using some code for `\limits` to define the stacking, however, I can't find anything in the rest of the source of the `amsmath` package showing how `\limits` works or how to use it without first specifying math mode.

Comment: what's the package that conflicts with `amsmath`?

Comment: This is the main focus of the `stackengine` package, http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\limits` is a TeX primitive used in the specification of super- and subscripts for math operators.

You could still use math mode, but just force the arguments to be typeset in text mode via some manipulation of the original `\overset` and `\underset` definitions:

[image: \overset and \underset without AMSmath]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\begin{document}
\mbox{}\phantom{Without}\llap{With} \verb|amsmath|: $\overset{\text{x}}{\text{a}}~\quad~\underset{\text{x}}{\text{a}}$

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\overset}[2]{\ensuremath{\mathop{\kern\z@\mbox{#2}}\limits^{\mbox{\scriptsize #1}}}}
\renewcommand{\underset}[2]{\ensuremath{\mathop{\kern\z@\mbox{#2}}\limits_{\mbox{\scriptsize #1}}}}
\makeatother

\mbox{}Without \verb|amsmath|: \overset{x}{a}~\quad~\underset{x}{a}

\end{document}
```

In the above minimal example, the redefinition of `\overset` and `\underset` style sets the two arguments in math mode, although it is not required to be specified explicitly. Additionally, since you're not interested in a math mode application, the binary relation spacing has been removed.

Comment: Is it possible to just use the array option like: `\begin{array}{c}
\text{x}\\text{a}  
\end{array}`

Comment: @azetina: Yes, and you can specify an optional argument to `array` as well, using `\begin{array}[t]{c}` for `\underset` and `\begin{array}[b]{c}` for `\overset`. However, the spacing will be different since the over/under placements are not limits; something that has to be corrected for.

Comment: The `\kern\z@` is not needed here. So, `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` are not needed here too.

Answer (score 17):

How to implement a `\textunderset` macro and its companion `\textoverset` depends on your real necessities. Here's one that tries keeping the main text and the subscript aligned with each other, while avoiding clashes between ascendents and discendents

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dynscriptsize}{\check@mathfonts\fontsize{\sf@size}{\z@}\selectfont}
\makeatother
\newcommand\textunderset[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr % center
      \strut#2\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
      \dynscriptsize\strut#1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand\textoverset[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr % center
      \dynscriptsize\strut#1\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
      \strut#2\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Abc \textunderset{du}{axy} \textunderset{ud}{axy} def

\bigskip

Abc \textoverset{du}{axy} \textoverset{ud}{axy} def

\bigskip

Abc \textoverset{du}{axy} \textunderset{ud}{axy} def
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to give the companion `\textoverset` for this, please?  It’s not clear to me how to adapt the definition of `\textunderset`.  I would ask it as a new question (and can do so if you’d like), but `\overset` was already mentioned in this question, so it seems more appropriate to suggest adding it here.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Done, with a brand new `\textoverset` macro

Comment: Fantastic, thankyou so much!  Yet again, I wish I could thank you more for all the wonderful help you provide here.  Just in case you’re ever in Stockholm on academic purposes, feel free look me up so I can at least buy you a beer :-)

Comment: @egreg: Sorry to be a bother. Actually my problem was the vertical disalign in `Abc \textoverset{aaaj}{axy}  \textoverset{aaab}{axy}`, caused by the j (or g, y). Even if it might not be relevant to the question here, is there a way to fix or mitigate this?

Comment: Maybe `\strut#1\cr  \vphantom{(Aj}#2\cr` for generally less jumpy behavior (consuming extra vertical space. May be useful for text with lots of oversets and undersets, to provide a consistent baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler and more understandable possibility using the `tabular` environment (100% LaTeX code)

- To adjust de **size** of the stacked text just change `\scriptsize` for your desired size. For example, `\tiny`
- To adjust the **separation** to the stacked text modify the value `-0.3` by your desired real value.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\textunderset}[2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#2\\[-0.3em]\scriptsize#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\textoverset}[2]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}\scriptsize#1\\[-0.3em]#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
Abc \textunderset{du}{axy} \textunderset{ud}{axy} def

\bigskip

Abc \textoverset{du}{axy} \textoverset{ud}{axy} def

\bigskip

Abc \textoverset{du}{axy} \textunderset{ud}{axy} def
\end{document}
```

[image]