# How to typeset an i with asterisk above?

Tags: xetex, amsmath

I tried it with a modification of `\overset` as suggested by Werner in this question: [Creating non-math mode substitutes for \overset and \underset not dependent on the amsmath package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42456/creating-non-math-mode-substitutes-for-overset-and-underset-not-dependent-on-t)

With the new command, I used `\overset{$*$}{ı}`, but the asterisk is too high and increases the line height. How can I overset the asterisk as in a dotted i?

In German, there is an internal I for gender-neutral forms like “TeXnikerIn” *TeXnician* for “TeXnikerin” (female) or “TeXniker” (male). Then there is the suggestion to combine it with an asterisk (“TeXniker*In”) for genderqueer people. So my idea is to use a lowercase i with an asterisk instead of a dot as an agglutination.

Comment: I had the [same idea among others](http://kowist.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/wortkorrekturen/) before L. Pusch announced the exclamation mark as another alternative. Perhaps I’ll patch Linux Libertine/Biolinum soon.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a “hand made i with asterisk”:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\asti}{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \leavevmode
  {\ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{.8ex}{\fontsize{\ssf@size}{0}\selectfont*}%
    \hidewidth\cr
    \i\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here \asti s \asti t.

\LARGE
Here \asti s \asti t.
\end{document}
```

The `\check@mathfonts` instruction is needed to access the scriptscript size for the current font size.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't affect your answer in any way but the idiomatic phrase is "Here it is."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I realized it after some minutes, when reloading the page; however, since also the asterisk above the ‘i’ is nonstandard, I'll leave it as is. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

It's very simple with the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand\astered[1]{\accentset{\ast}{#1}}
\begin{document}

 $ \astered{\i}\quad \astered{\imath}$

 \boldmath
 $ \astered{\i}\quad \astered{\imath}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is for math mode only.

Comment: @egreg: I thought it had to be so, from the O.P.'s formulation.

Comment: It has not, I just tried it with math mode because I did not know of an alternative. Very useful answer anyway.

Answer (score 7):

`i⃰` or `ı⃰` U+20F0 ‘Combining Asterisk Above’ after either *i* or *dotless i* (U+0131), since you’ve tagged your question with `xetex`, i.e. can use most of Unicode (if you have the right fonts, of which there seem to be few).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,lmodern}

\newcommand\testtext[2][i⃰ / ı⃰]{\noindent{#1 \hfill \textit{#1} \hfill \textbf{#1 \hfill \textit{#1}} \hfill \textsc{#1} \hfill – #2}\par}
\newcommand\testfont[1]{\fontspec{#1}\testtext{#1}}

\begin{document}
\huge
\textup{\testtext{serif}}
\textsf{\testtext{sans-serif}}
\texttt{\testtext{mono}}
\testfont{Linux Libertine O}
\testfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\testfont{XITS}
\testfont{STIXGeneral}
\testfont{Geneva}
\testfont{Georgia}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code]

Comment: But I have not, I use Linux Libertine.

Comment: Testı⃰ng... Hmm, looks like Linux Libertine indeed lacks the combining asterisk character. FreeSerif does have it, though.

Comment: STIX has it, too, but it looks misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

using https://github.com/loveencounterflow/cxltx-styles#cxltx-style-accentbox, you could simply write the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{cxltx-style-accentbox}
\begin{document}

\textit{Some variations with an asterisk placed above an `i':}
i\upaccent{\tiny *}{\i}i\upaccent{\tiny *}{\i}i\upaccent{\tiny *}{\i}
\textit{i\upaccent{\tiny *}{\i}i\upaccent{\tiny *}{\i}i\upaccent{\tiny *}{\i}}

\end{document}
```

CXLTX AccentBox is a copy of a very thoughtfully implemented [module by A.S. Berdnikov](http://www.eutypon.gr/eutypon/pdf/e2000-05/e05-a04.pdf) which does not seem to have found its way into current LaTeX distros; however, installing [CXLTX Styles](https://github.com/loveencounterflow/cxltx-styles) should pose no great difficulties.