# Easiest way to align two texts that go beyond the textwidth?

Tags: spacing

If I have a paragraph, and I want to line up a phonetic transcription with each word, what's the easiest way to do this? I want it to look something like this:

```
When she turned back the man was regarding her above his sleeve, which he had
wɛn  ʃi  təɹnd  bæk  ðə  mæn wəz ɹəɡɑɹdɪŋ  həɹ əbʌv  hɪz sliv    wɪtʃ  hi hæd

pressed too cut on his cheek.
pɹɛst   tu  kʌt ɔn hɪz tʃik
```

And so on. I've could put this in a table, of course, but it's unlikely that I'd get the same number of words in each line, and the line breaks would start to look horrendous.

Comment: How do you want to provide the phonetic translation? Word by word? And can one assume that the translation is at most as wider as the word itself?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Word by word, and it's unlikely that any transcription would ever be longer than the regular orthographic form.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very simpleminded proposal (which also reveals that I have no idea about phonetics, so I hope that you do not mind me making up symbols). Whether or not this is the easiest way I can't say (I guess not) and it has obvious downsides as it does not support hyphenation. Yet this may give you a start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\tp[2]{% based on \textunderset from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42477
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      ##\hfil\cr % center
      \strut#1\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
      \strut#2\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\tp{When}{W$\varepsilon$n} \tp{she}{shi} \tp{turned}{t\"orned}
\tp{back}{b\"ack}  \tp{the}{$\sigma$e} \tp{man}{m\"an} \tp{was}{wos}
\tp{regarding}{regarding}  \tp{her}{h\"or} \tp{above}{abof} \tp{his}{his}
\tp{sleeve,}{slif} \tp{which}{wich} \tp{he}{hi} \tp{had}{had}
\tp{pressed}{pressed} \tp{too}{too} \tp{cut}{cut} \tp{on}{on} \tp{his}{his}
\tp{cheek.}{chik}
\end{document}
```

[image]